# Why does this condition fail when i=0 in the following code?

Tags: c

Why does this condition fail when `i` becomes 0 ?
`i++` means `i` becomes -4 from -5 how is the condition true as initially `i` was -5?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    static int i = -5;
    if (i++) //why does this condition fails when it becomes 0
    {
        printf("%d ", i);//recurtion starts
        main(10);
    }
}
```

---

what is the difference between `i++` and `++i` in the for loop?

Comment: integral values convert implicitly to bool, with 0 meaning false, and all other values meaning true. Also, your program is malformed, due to calling main

Comment: There is no reason to make a variable `static` in `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does this condition fail when i=0

An `if` statement will not execute if the condition in it returns false ( which is equal to 0 ). That is , the statement will execute only if the condition return true ( or non zero value )

```
if( <condition> )
```

If the condition returns false ( `0` ) , then the `if` statement will not be executed. The same goes for a while loop.

In other words, the `if` statement works as

```
if ( /* Statement or condition is true */ )
    //  execute the code
```

For your question

> what is the difference between i++ and ++i in for loop?

Consider this for loop

```
int i;
for ( i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ )
    // some code
```

This loop is equivalent to

```
int i;
i = 0;
while ( i < 5 )
{
    // some code
    i++;             
}
```

If your for loop contained `++i` instead of `i++`, that is

```
int i;
for ( i = 0 ; i < 5 ; ++i )
    // some code
```

Then it would be equivalent to

```
int i;
i = 0;
while ( i < 5 )
{
    // some code
    ++i;             
}
```

So, as you can see , the `i++` or `++i` is executed last, so in short, both the for loops would work as the same

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then Arun A.S answered correctly. If an 'if' statement returns 0, execution will stop. This is the code you should be using.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        static int i = -5;
        if (i<10) 
        {
            ++i;
            printf("%d ", i);//recurtion starts
            main(10);
        }
    }
```

OR if you want a user number, you would do this....

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    int recursion(int user_num){
    static int i = -5;
        if (i<user_num)
        {
            ++i;
            printf("%d ", i);//recurtion starts
            recursion(user_num);
        }
    }

    int main()
    { int user_num;
    scanf("%d",&user_num);
    recursion(user_num);
    }
```